# Error delete from DataGridView and Access Database

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I select a row from my DataGridView to populate my TextBoxes I proceed to a delete button click to delete the selected row from my DataGridView and from my Access Database. I get a ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less then the size of the collection Parameter name: index. The error was for this line. Dim custStr As String = dgBartenderLabels.SelectedRows(0).Cells("CustNo").Value

```
  Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        Try
            Dim ConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Gwen\Documents\Database1.mdb"
            Dim sqlStr As String
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim OleDBConn1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnStr)
            Dim ds As New DataSet()

            OleDBConn1.Open()
            Dim custStr As String = dgBartenderLabels.SelectedRows(0).Cells("CustNo").Value  'ERROR HAPPENS HERE
            If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                sqlStr = "DELETE FROM TblLabelCustom_copy WHERE [CustNo] =  custStr"
                Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, OleDBConn1)
                cmd.CommandText = sqlStr
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Deletion aborted", "Aborted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

            End If
            dgBartenderLabels.Update()
            OleDBConn1.Close()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You are doing it all wrong.  Populate your `DataTable` by calling `Fill` on a data adapter. Bind that to a `BindingSource` bind the `BindingSource` to the grid AND the `TextBoxes`.  To delete the current record, call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource`.  To commit that and any other changes to the database, call `Update` on the same data adapter and pass the same `DataTable`.

Comment: Tried several different ways to delete this data from the access database and also the DataGridView with no luck. Do you have a link to an example.

Comment: You don't need luck.  You just need to do it the proper way.  Have you attempted to follow the instructions I provided?  Have you researched the parts you don't understand, e.g. read the documentation for the `BindingSource` class and searched for how to bind `TextBoxes`?  If you have tried what you think is correct and it didn't work, update your question with the new code and explain exactly what happened when you tried it.